# Xpath to get the CSS property "background image" of DIV

Tags: selenium2

What would be the Xpath to get the background-image CSS Property of a DIV tag whose ID is mentioned in Selenium Webdriver?

Example:

```
<div id="abc", style="width: 538px !important; height: 242px !important; background-image: url(http://test.com/images/abc.png); position: relative; background-position: 0% 0%;>
```

I want to find this image with url: `http://test.com/images/abc.png`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you know the div's ID, and you want to verify the CSS background-image property? Or do you only know the CSS background-image property, and you want to use that to identify the div and then do some other testing on it?

Answer (score 2):

Typically HTML IDs are unique; if you know the ID, you do not need to know the element tag.  Of course it is possible to write a web page that uses duplicate IDs.  If your web page has duplicate IDs, you should complain to the developer.  For the rest of my answer, I will assume unique IDs.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268210/how-to-get-second-attribute-level-with-seleniums-xpath), XPath doesn't actually know anything about CSS styles.

I also assume you are using the Java language binding.  I Googled for "webdriver webelement"; the second link took me to the [WebElement javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), where I found the [getCssValue method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29).  Try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));
String bgImage = element.getCssValue("background-image");
```